# is OrderByRaw() safe?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is the below code safe from SQL injection?

```
    if ($request->has('sort')) {
        $s = $request->sort;
        if ($request->has('asc')) {
            $a = $request->asc;
        } else {
            $a = 'asc';
        }
        $query->orderByRaw("ISNULL({$s}), {$s} " . $a);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As the name suggests, it inserts a *raw* expression. That is, unsanitized.

If you’re wanting to sort a query, just sort when the require query string parameter(s) are provided:

```php
if ($sort = $request->query('sort')) {
    $direction = $request->query('direction');

    if (! in_array($direction, ['asc', 'desc'])) {
        $direction = 'asc'; // default direction
    }

    $query->orderBy($sort, $direction);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it should be fine if I enclose the variables above in backticks?

Comment: Not necessarily. What if someone submits something like `key\`; DROP TABLE \`users\`; --`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with RAW queries are much more in the bindings (user data) than in the sql query itself, that's why you should avoid them. But it is safer if you add the bindings separately:

```
public function orderByRaw($sql, $bindings = []) {...}
```

Comment: I would love to avoid them but I don't believe you can order By ISNULL without :o/

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach to achieve this kind of conditional query using `when` for example:

```
// You have the $query instance already...
```

```php
$sort = $request->get('sort');

$query->when($sort, function($query) use($request) {
    $order = $request->asc ?: 'asc';
    return $query->orderBy($sort, $order);
});
```

Now, the `orderBy` will be applied only when the `$sort` is available and you can add more query constrains further and execute it like:

```php
// $query->where(...);

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: I still need a raw Order By because I want to use ISNULL to exclude null values.